# issue with viewing an order

Tags: php, mysql

i have created this code to view orders once submitted to database.
this issue doesnt happen all the time but sometimes i get mysql errors.

and it reports these lines

```
$FIRSTNAME=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"FIRSTNAME");
$LASTNAME=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"LASTNAME");
$EMAIL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"EMAIL");
$PHONE=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PHONE");
$ADDRESS1=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ADDRESS1");
$ADDRESS2=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ADDRESS2");
$CITY=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CITY");
$STATE=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"STATE");
```

not everyone who orders will get this error but itll pop up and block out a customers name with the following errors.

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 39
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 40
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 41
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 42
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 43
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 44
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 45
>
> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 3 in /home/florida/public_html/vieworder.php on line 46

can anyone assist me on telling me what i did wrong? thanks

more code added below:

```
<body>
<span class="TextC">
<?
$memberid = str_replace("'","''",$_REQUEST['ID']);  
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "florida_fields", "fields321") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("florida_fields");

$queryt = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE OID = '$memberid' ";
$resultt = mysql_query($queryt) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$numt=mysql_numrows($resultt);

$ORDERID=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ORDERID");
$CART=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CART");
$ORDERTOTAL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PRICE");
$CUSTOMER=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CUSTOMER");
$PAYMETHOD=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PAYMETHOD");
$PAID=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PAID");
$MYPICKUP=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PICKUPDATE");
$COMMENTS=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"COMMENTS");
$GRANDTOTAL=$ORDERTOTAL;



$queryt = "SELECT * FROM MEMBERS WHERE MID = '$CUSTOMER' ";
$resultt = mysql_query($queryt) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$numt=mysql_numrows($resultt);

$FIRSTNAME=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"FIRSTNAME");
$LASTNAME=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"LASTNAME");
$EMAIL=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"EMAIL");
$PHONE=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"PHONE");
$ADDRESS1=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ADDRESS1");
$ADDRESS2=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"ADDRESS2");
$CITY=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"CITY");
$STATE=mysql_result($resultt,$it,"STATE");



?>
<? echo $FIRSTNAME?><br />
<? echo $LASTNAME?><br />
<? echo $EMAIL?><br />
<? echo $PHONE?><br />
<? echo $ADDRESS1?><br />
<? echo $ADDRESS2?><br />
<? echo $CITY?><br />
<? echo $STATE?><br />
<br />
<br />
Pick-Up Date: <? echo $MYPICKUP?><br />
Order #: <? echo $ORDERID?><br /><br />
<? echo $CART?><br />

Comments: <? echo $COMMENTS?><br /><br />
Sub Total: $<? echo $GRANDTOTAL?><br />
<?php
$paypal = 'paypal';
$check = 'check';

if ($PAYMETHOD == "paypal")
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = " . number_format(($GRANDTOTAL * .045), 2);
    $GRANDTOTAL = floatval(number_format(($GRANDTOTAL * 1.045), 2));
}
    elseif ($PAYMETHOD == "check")
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
?><br />

Grand Total: $<? echo $GRANDTOTAL?><br />
Payment Method: <? echo $PAYMETHOD?></span><span class="TextB"><br />
<br />
<br />
<form>
<input type="button" class="TextA" onClick="window.print()" value="Print this page">
</form>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us the entire code.

Comment: Can you share more details about how you obtain `$resultt` and `$it`

Comment: when someone orders from my store, the order goes into my database and i use this view order to retrieve what they have ordered.

Comment: Have you seen any books or tutorials on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your `SELECT * FROM MEMBERS ...` is returning an empty set.  You can guard against that by wrapping the code where you access the results in:

```
if (numt>0){
    // work with results here.
}
```

From the code you posted, I can't tell where you're setting `$it` which is used in your call to `mysql_result`.  That being said, for what you're doing, you shouldn't be using `mysql_result` in the first place.

Instead you can do something like this:

```
$resultt = mysql_query($queryt) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$numt=mysql_numrows($resultt);
if ($numt > 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultt);
    $FIRSTNAME=$row["FIRSTNAME"];
    $LASTNAME=$row["LASTNAME"];
    $EMAIL=$row["EMAIL"];
    $PHONE=$row["PHONE"];
    // etc...
}
```

Finally, you should also look into using MySQLi as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and also into using prepared statements to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: so i would put if(numt>0){ above select?

Comment: No.  After the line `$numt=mysql_numrows($resultt);`  That's where you check how many rows your select statement returned.

Comment: I edited my second code sample to be a little clearer about how to combine my two suggestions.

Comment: so i will be wrapping the last part of the code u presented correct and at the end of statement will be } from if statment